# How to prevent Android Factory reset?

Tags: android

I want to catch/listen to factory reset event in Android. Is there any braodcasted intent or any other way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could be out of context but I would really like to know why you want to do that ?

Comment: And I want to catch/listen the upcoming end of the world in december.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: not even possible if application is an system can we then call some api to do this, As device owner can perform this action system application should also be able to do the same.What your thought on this @CommonsWare

Comment: @piyush: There is not an API for everything. As I wrote, Android does not appear to have *any* means to detect a factory reset, let alone a documented and supported API to detect a factory reset.

Comment: thanks i was talking about this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html#DISALLOW_SAFE_BOOT

Comment: @piyush: First, that is safe boot, not factory reset. Second, that blocks the ability to enter safe boot, while this Stack Overflow question is about being notified about a pending factory reset.

Comment: sorry sorry my bad commented wrong link was talking about this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html#DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET thanks

Comment: @piyush: That blocks factory reset, while this Stack Overflow question is about being notified about a pending factory reset.

Comment: thanks i will raise another question, my comments was not related to question, it was for a way from which we can disable factory reset.